# AngularJS - filter orderBy from jsonRequest

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to order a column in my html table by name.

```
<tr ng-repeat="setting in detailsExample.versionExample.settings | orderBy:'name'">
```

This is the json I am trying to connect it with $filter

```
jsonRequest.request('/api/request.php', 'APP', 'GET', dataObj, function (dataReturned) {
    $scope.appDetails.versionDetails = dataReturned.data;
    var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
    if (isEmpty($scope.appDetails.versionDetails.settings)) {
        $scope.appDetails.versionDetails.settings = {}
        $filter.appDetails.versionDetails.settings = {};
    }
});
```

I have been using the AngularJS documentation as a guide: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/wky9vrbt/

Is there something wrong with my variable? var orderBy = $filter('orderBy'); ?

Comment: If you do as @eras0r suggested : $filter('orderBy')($scope.appDetails.versionDetails.settings,'name'); you will have the sorted list as a result. You will just need to bind it to scope ($scope.orderedList = [thecodeahead]) and use it in ng-repeat (ng-repeat="item in orderedList")

Comment: @Okazari So something more along the lines of this? if (isEmpty($scope.appDetails.versionDetails.settings)) {
                $filter('orderBy')($scope.appDetails.versionDetails.settings,'setting_name');
            }
        });

Comment: yeah that looks like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use angular's built-in orderBy filter directly in your HTML view you do not need to do the follwoing call in javascript.

```
var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
```

You can simply remove that line of code.

However, when using the orderBy filter in Javascript, you must specify the array you want to be ordered by specifiing it inside an additional bracket, Here is an example:

```
$filter('orderBy')($scope.appDetails.versionDetails.settings);
```

Comment: You also need a 2nd var to give the property name you will order by. $filter('orderBy')($scope.appDetails.versionDetails.settings,'name');